# Generating multinomial random variables by row in big dataset in R. Need to speed up

Tags: r, random, dplyr, purrr, multinomial

I have data with the following structure and I am trying to implement a function that, for each row, assigns a choice using a random multinomial generator with values `<Educ_W1:Educ_W5>` as the vector of probabilities (they add to one by row). Thus, for each row the new variable will a values between 1 and 5. 
I have managed to implement it myself, but I trying to find a faster way to do it, since it takes too long in the current version (couple of days. Data contains over 1 million observations).

`| IDhh|Year |Educ_W |Educ_H |   Educ_W1|   Educ_W2|   Educ_W3|   Educ_W4|   Educ_W5|
|----:|:----|:------|:------|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|    1|1975 |2      |2      | 0.1645188| 0.3362659| 0.3940354| 0.0831637| 0.0220162|
|    2|1975 |2      |2      | 0.1645188| 0.3362659| 0.3940354| 0.0831637| 0.0220162|
|    5|1975 |2      |1      | 0.5103815| 0.2092249| 0.2285570| 0.0392398| 0.0125968|
|    6|1975 |3      |3      | 0.0811203| 0.1535407| 0.5528233| 0.1486548| 0.0638609|
|    8|1975 |1      |1      | 0.5103815| 0.2092249| 0.2285570| 0.0392398| 0.0125968|
|   10|1975 |3      |2      | 0.1645188| 0.3362659| 0.3940354| 0.0831637| 0.0220162|`

Currently I'm implementing the function in the following way, but I takes extremely long. Here, the variable "IDhh" uniquely identifies each row. The function `rMultinom` from the R package `Hmisc`  generate Multinomial Random Variables with varying probabilities.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  select(IDhh, Year, Educ_W, Educ_H, Educ_W1 : Educ_W5) %>% 
  nest(-IDhh) %>% 
  mutate(
    wanted_W = map(data, ~ rMultinom(t(c(.x$Educ_W1, .x$Educ_W2, .x$Educ_W3, 
                                         .x$Educ_W4, .x$Educ_W5)), 1))) %>%
  unnest()
```

`

The desired output looks like this, where "Wanted_W" is the new variable.

`|    IDhh| wanted_W|Year |Educ_W |   Educ_W1|   Educ_W2|   Educ_W3|   Educ_W4|   Educ_W5|
|-------:|--------:|:----|:------|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|   18806|        3|1975 |3      | 0.1851884| 0.1577067| 0.4749609| 0.1394014| 0.0427427|
| 2442099|        4|2010 |1      | 0.4436620| 0.0987973| 0.3296288| 0.1013606| 0.0265513|
| 1351429|        3|1995 |3      | 0.0708855| 0.1023657| 0.5904598| 0.1784980| 0.0577910|
|  250232|        3|1980 |5      | 0.0337913| 0.0347975| 0.2156134| 0.2315768| 0.4842209|
| 1802868|        3|2005 |3      | 0.0371280| 0.0772428| 0.6054841| 0.2024385| 0.0777067|
|  715077|        2|1985 |3      | 0.1149756| 0.1412112| 0.5458910| 0.1413975| 0.0565248|`

Comment: I suggest you to use the function `put` for creating a reproducible example. Besides this, I think the bottleneck is the function `rMultinom`. In order deal with massive dataset you need operators that can be vectorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling `Hmisc::rMultinom` a million times (once for each row in your data), you can just give the probability argument to the function as a matrix. Each row in the matrix will then define a distinct multinomial distribution.

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2018-02-09

library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

# Generate category probabilities
n <- 1e6
unifs <- replicate(5, runif(n))
probs <- sweep(unifs, 1, apply(unifs, 1, sum), "/")
colnames(probs) <- paste0("p", seq_len(ncol(probs)))

df <- as_tibble(probs)

system.time({
  probs <- as.matrix(df %>% select(p1:p5))
  res <- df %>% 
    mutate(rcat = Hmisc::rMultinom(probs, 1))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    9.25    0.15    9.50

res
#> # A tibble: 1,000,000 x 6
#>            p1         p2         p3         p4         p5  rcat
#>         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 0.14607852 0.07709049 0.33798110 0.22154639 0.21730349    p4
#>  2 0.12813691 0.23952958 0.11025717 0.31642808 0.20564827    p4
#>  3 0.19137423 0.24349984 0.06855848 0.23421041 0.26235703    p3
#>  4 0.30227095 0.03050219 0.27667295 0.28389810 0.10665580    p3
#>  5 0.10096040 0.03334545 0.07350112 0.38768513 0.40450791    p4
#>  6 0.32430441 0.22123172 0.13317669 0.08001760 0.24126959    p2
#>  7 0.32710720 0.14134942 0.25371663 0.20344497 0.07438178    p1
#>  8 0.21841291 0.23480314 0.25563400 0.06838794 0.22276200    p3
#>  9 0.21164692 0.19809418 0.15415735 0.15095640 0.28514514    p1
#> 10 0.02220492 0.23105648 0.35661756 0.08688459 0.30323645    p3
#> # ... with 999,990 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this without the `rMultinom` function, by generating a random Uniform variable and checking in which interval it lies, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#To_simulate_a_multinomial_distribution):

```
set.seed(1234)
n=1000000
library(data.table)

# Sample data -----------------------------------------------------------
create_probs <- function(x)
{
  y = sample(1:10,x)
  y = as.list(y/sum(y))
  return(y)
}
p_dt = data.table(id=1:n)
p_dt =p_dt[,c("Educ_w1","Educ_w2","Educ_w3","Educ_w4","Educ_w5"):=create_probs(5),by=1:nrow(p_dt)]


# Function --------------------------------------------------------------
p_dt[,U:=runif(1,0,1),1:nrow(p_dt)]
p_dt = p_dt[,Educ_w:=min(which(cumsum(unlist(.SD))>U)),1:nrow(p_dt),
            .SDcols=c("Educ_w1","Educ_w2","Educ_w3","Educ_w4","Educ_w5")]

head(p_dt)
```

Sample output:

```
   id    Educ_w1    Educ_w2   Educ_w3    Educ_w4    Educ_w5          U Educ_w
1:  1 0.06666667 0.20000000 0.1666667 0.26666667 0.30000000 0.49320836      4
2:  2 0.36842105 0.05263158 0.1052632 0.26315789 0.21052632 0.54415445      4
3:  3 0.25925926 0.18518519 0.1111111 0.37037037 0.07407407 0.65840751      4
4:  4 0.29032258 0.09677419 0.3225806 0.06451613 0.22580645 0.26604797      1
5:  5 0.22222222 0.16666667 0.1111111 0.05555556 0.44444444 0.05887458      1
6:  6 0.31034483 0.17241379 0.2758621 0.20689655 0.03448276 0.98659704      5
```

The function part of this takes about 8 seconds to run on my pc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks so much for your answer. The reason I did not do it that ways is that many individuals share the same vector of probabilities. With your method they will all end up with the same choice, while with  "rMultinom" the outcome is still random for rows with same values in Educ_W1:Educ_W5. Best!

Comment: Oops, sorry! I misread the question and assumed the probabilities were determined at random as well. I have updated my answer with a solution that I hope is closer to what you are looking for, although I see another answer has also been added that looks very simple and promising ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was here looking for a solution of the same problem. Honestly I didn't find it, but maybe I can give a better solution to you.

`z = mapply(rmultinom, n = 1, size = 1, prob = split(probs, c(col(probs))))`

All functions are built-in functions of R, `probs` are column-wise, in the sense that one column of `probs` identifies the probabilities of one draw of multinomia. The result is a matrix. Each column has the result (1 for the class of the outcome, 0 for the others) and is 60% faster